# CSS Flexbox in a Form

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to use the flex display property on my web form in order to have two text fields side-by side and automatically growing to fill the space. I chose to use flex over a table layout because I want them to move to their own line when the window shrinks.

I believe I am misunderstanding how to use flexbox.

Below is my work so far (simplified for posting here). I am using a fieldset as a flex parent, and each form element which should "grow" side-by-side is encased in a div (set to `display: inline` so they can be on the same line). I also have a legend for the fieldset, set to `display:block` and `width:100%` so that it will be on its own line.

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/1j2c3sf0/)

```css
fieldset {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: none;
}

label {
    display: none;
}

legend {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

fieldset > div {
    display: inline;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>These are Text Fields</legend>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="text1">
            <label for="text1">Text Field</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="text2">
            <label for="text2">More Text</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

As you can see, the divs are each on their own line (despite the `display: inline` and flexbox stuff). If you add a border to the div elements, you'll see that they are 100% width right now; but even if you manually define a width (like 30%), they remain on their own lines.

How can I use flex to display the divs side-by-side and allow them to scale to fill the parent's width?

Comment: See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=949476 and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=262679

In simple terms, `fieldset` has a dedicated renderer which cannot be overridden.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thank you. I hadn't found that question in my original searches -- I didn't suspect it to be an inherent fieldset thing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

EDIT: **This bug has been fixed in Firefox and Chrome.** The example as originally posted in the question now works as intended.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1230207
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375693

---

Two things here:

1. When you do `display: flex` on an element, every single direct child is affected. So in your example (if it were working) the legend will also be displayed on the same line.
2. For whatever reason, `fieldset` doesn't like to play nicely with flexbox. since you don't want the legend to be on the same line anyway, I would suggest specifically wrapping the elements you want to be on the same line.

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>These are Text Fields</legend>
        <div class="flex-wrapper">
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="text1">
                <label for="text1">Text Field</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="text2">
                <label for="text2">More Text</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

```css
fieldset {
    border: none;
}

.flex-wrapper {
 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;   
    align-items: stretch;
}

.flex-wrapper > div {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

label {
    display: none;
}

legend {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Indeed it did totally not work with fieldset. Took me half an hour.. Thanks! ;)